# Why does the $\phi$-component of the Schwarzschild geodesic represent specific angular momentum?

Tags: general-relativity, angular-momentum, metric-tensor, geodesics

The $\phi$-component of a geodesic in Schwarzschild spacetime is: $$0=\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(r^2 \sin^2\theta\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial\tau}\right),$$
which can be integrated to get:
$$r^2\sin^2\theta\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}=l,$$
where $l$ is constant. I understand that since this is constant, it somehow represents a conservation of angular momentum — but I'm not entirely clear how this solution to the geodesic necessarily *represents* [specific angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_angular_momentum). Please may someone explain the link?

Comment: Did you try to write down the action of a massive particle in the Schwarzschild spacetime? You can then write down the Euler-Lagrange equation for $\phi$. Since $\phi$ is a cyclic coordinate, its canonical momentum is conserved. The canonical momentum is precisely the angular momentum (divided by the mass of the particle).

Comment: The title refers to “the $\phi$-component of the Schwarzschild geodesic”. The body refers to “the $\phi$-component of the Schwarzschild metric”. The metric is not the geodesic, and metrics don’t have $\phi$ components.

Comment: @psm I hadn't tried this - after looking into relativistic Lagrangians a bit I think I understand the logic to your method - although the maths itself is a bit beyond my scope! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Ghoster Apologies - that was a typo. Fixed it now.

Comment: The first sentence still starts with “The $\phi$-component of the Schwarzschild metric”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi$ be a Killing vector on some spacetime. By this we mean that $L_\xi g_{\mu\nu}=0$ where $L_\xi$ is the Lie derivative along $\xi$. It can be calculated in coordinates as $$L_\xi g_{\mu\nu}=\xi^\lambda \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}+\partial_\mu \xi^\lambda g_{\lambda \nu}+\partial_\nu \xi^\lambda g_{\mu\lambda}.$$

In particular, imagine that $\xi$ is one of the coordinate vectors. In other words, imagine that $\xi = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$ for fixed $\alpha$. Then $\xi^\mu = \delta^\mu_\alpha$ and then

$$L_{\partial_\alpha}g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\alpha g_{\mu\nu}.$$

Thus a coordinate vector is Killing if and only if the metric components are all independent of the corresponding coordinate.

Now, if $\xi$ is a Killing vector and $\gamma^\mu(\tau)$ is a geodesic, then the quantity $$Q_\gamma[\xi]=\xi_\mu(\gamma(\tau)) \dot{\gamma}^\mu(\tau)$$

is conserved along the curve. In other words $$\dfrac{d}{d\tau}Q_\gamma[\xi]=0.$$

In Schwarzschild spacetime, consider the coordinate vector $\partial_\phi$. The metric components are clearly independent of $\phi$. As a result $\partial_\phi$ is Killing. Therefore, given any geodesic $\gamma$, $Q_{\gamma}[\partial_\phi]$ is conserved along the geodesic. This is what we define as angular momentum.

As to why we define with angular momentum, well, it is because we already know from classical mechanics that angular momentum is the conserved quantity associated to rotational symmetry by Noether's theorem. A Killing vector generates a symmetry, in the case of $\partial_\phi$ it is clearly a rotational symmetry, so it is most fitting that the associated conserved quantity be what we define as angular momentum.